# Where doe crypto.rng come from

Tags: javascript, node.js

Looking at some code that makes use of what I guess to be the generation of a random number of 32 bytes:

```
crypto.rng(32)
```

where

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
```

So my first assumption (being a java dev) is that crypto, being a node.js thing would have an rng function, but no I am wrong.

Can someone please point me in the right directions.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your code monkey-patched the standard object.

Comment: hmmm, it does not appear that way because I don't see evidence of that

Comment: Well if the `require()` works then that means the code is somewhere in your repository, and you can just look at it.

Comment: no it isn't, that is why I am confused - it can't be found but it must be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.rng` method of the `crypto` module is an undocumented alias of the `.randomBytes` method.

You can find that here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1e8d110e640c658e4f6ed7540db62d063269ba6c/lib/crypto.js#L165

docs for `.randomBytes`: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback